# Do firestore batch writes get re-run automatically on failure?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

While going through the official documentation I found out that transactions are automatically re-run a finite number of times by the SDK on failure, however in case of Batch Writes it is not explicitly mentioned.

The documentation does mention that batch writes are atomic just like transactions but that does not necessarily implies that they get re-run also on failure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Batch writes are not retried if there is a failure.  The entire thing is just rolled back, and you have to figure out for yourself if you want to retry.

Transactions are retried because they are explicitly trying to make a change based on the contents of existing document.  Since those documents could change between the round trip between the client and server, the retry is necessary to automatically handle that case, if it happens.  Batch writes don't have this problem, since they are atomic, but not really transactional in nature.

Comment: Thanks for giving justification of their non-transnational behavior.

Comment: But this also raises a question that if I have a function performing a batch write operation where I have also initialized/created my batch object by doing: `let batch=db.batch()`. So if this batch operation is failed, would it be a good idea to recall that function again as on each recall a new batch object will get instantiated. Or is there a certain "_good practice_" of **retrying** batch writes in firestore?

Comment: A batch will only fail outright if you've done something wrong, or you violate a security rule.  In that case, retrying the exact thing in the same circumstances won't help anything.  There is no "best practice" here other than correcting the mistake.

Comment: but aren't Batch Writes fail on concurrent edits too? I mean if for instance in my app too many users simultaneously want to update the same field of one of my document won't it be an issue in this case?

Comment: I don't think that's the way they work.  It should be just like a document write where the last write wins.  The difference with batch is that all the writes will hit at the same time.  If you need to guard against contention, use a transaction, since the transaction will retry if it detects that case.

Comment: Will there be any performance difference when using BatchWrite? Do they write much faster and whole batch commit is atomic?